# How to change n-th element in list of lists with python list comprehensions?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of sublists like that:

```
posts = [[1, 'text1', 0], [1, 'text2', 0]]
```

and function `change_text(text)`

how can i apply this function only to text elements of each sub-list?

i have tried this:

```
posts = [change_text(post[1]) for post in posts]
```

but i got only texts `['changed_text1', 'changed_text2']`

Comment: How the function looks like? What's your expected output?

Comment: this example is simplyfied but lets assume that it change 'text' to 'changed text', what i expect to get is [[1, 'changed_text1', 0], [1, 'changed_text2', 0], not text fields only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a list within the list comprehension

```
>>> change_text = lambda x:'changed_'+x
>>> posts = [[1, 'text1', 0], [1, 'text2', 0]]
>>> [[post[0],change_text(post[1]),post[2]] for post in posts]
[[1, 'changed_text1', 0], [1, 'changed_text2', 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks, that is simple when you saw it at least once.

Comment: Yeah, I was waiting for your comment to post the answer

Answer (score 0):

One  way could be

```
[[post[0], change_text(post[1]), post[2]] for post in posts]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do an edit directly on the second element itself without creating another new list.

```
>>> change_text = lambda x:'changed_'+x
>>> posts = [[1, 'text1', 0], [1, 'text2', 0]]
>>> for m in posts:
        m[1] = change_text(m[1])


>>> posts
[[1, 'changed_text1', 0], [1, 'changed_text2', 0]]
```